# How to get the error message behind a yellow exclamation mark in Solution Explorer References?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, solution-explorer

There are [tons of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=visual%20studio%20yellow%20exclamation%20mark) here on Stack Overflow about how to get rid of the yellow exclamation mark ⚠️ in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer:

[image]

What I never found until now is a way to actually get the error message behind the yellow exclamation mark.

I've tried:

- Hover with the mouse over the yellow exclamation mark icon (nothing happens).
- Clicking the erroneous reference and inspect the Properties window (no usable info).
- Set build verbosity to maximum and inspect the output (no useful information *to me*).

So I'm rather clueless.

**My question:**

How to see the reason/error message for a yellow exclamation mark in Visual Studio Solution Explorer in the References section?

Comment: open the project file with a text editor and look if there are any hard coded paths that are not available on your system

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm not looking for a solution to fix this, I'm looking for a way to get the error message.

Comment: In my case the actual underlying issue was resolved by [applying this](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1499#issuecomment-322874417) to my CSPROJ file. Still, this does not answer my question of how to see the actual error message.

Comment: there is no real help for such issues. it happens when you reference a dll for a higher .net version, have invalid paths for referenced files. this was always a mess to diag.

Answer (score -2):

Right click on Reference, then click in manage package nuget. It will show a button to update the references. After that build the project to apply the changes.